# Nested foreach of datatable to xydataseries

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a `datatable` that is created from merging multiple others, data originally comes from imported excel files. I essentially have columns of values, although the amount of columns and names are unknown in advance and the first two columns are always to be ignored.

I'm trying to create an `xydataseries<double, double>()` for each column of my `datatable` where; x is an incrementing integer from 1 and y = column data. I've tried this on a click event (wpf);

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn i in dt.Columns)
        {
            var x = 1;
            var series = new XyDataSeries<double, double>();
            foreach (DataRow j in dt.Rows)
            {
                Convert.ToDouble(j);
                series.Append(x++,j);
            }
        }
    }
```

But i get an error on the last line for j - cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'double'.

I am new to c# and programming in general, thank you for any help.

Comment: use ``j[i]`` to access the cell. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035(v=vs.110).aspx - this than can be converted to double.

Comment: I am getting an error, 'cannot convert from object to double' when i do this -                     Convert.ToDouble(j[i]);
                    series.Append(one++, j[i]);

Comment: You have to pass the converted value to the second line change your code to `var d = Convert.ToDouble(j[i]); series.Append(x++, d);`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is the result of passing in a DataRow object as a parameter to series.Append when it is expecting a double. This is because Convert.ToDouble *returns* a double, meaning you have to assign the result to a new variable in order to use it. The original j variable remains unaltered. To get a double you must do:

`double newDouble = Convert.ToDouble(j);`

However this will error because Convert.ToDouble only works with objects which implement the IConvertible interface (which DataRow does not). Assuming that a value within the DataRow is what you are actually after, you can retrieve this value either by using the column index

`double newDouble = Convert.ToDouble(j[2]);`

or by column name

`double newDouble = Convert.ToDouble(j["ColumnName"]);`